# Python: Double underscores by themselves

Tags: python, variables

I stumbled this code:

```py
response_html, __, __ = render_new_grant_email(grant)
```

What do double underscores mean? I know single underscore placeholder `_`, but here it's double `__`.

Comment: Why do you think it means anything in particular?  The single underscore placeholder has no inherent meaning, it's just a convention.  The programmer here just wanted to be different, I guess.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: The double-underscores don't mean anything. What makes you think they do?

Answer (score 0):

An underscore in python is just a variable, usually used as a "temp" variable that you don't really want to name (mostly because you don't need it further in your code).

Two underscores are just the same.

The `render_new_grant_email` function returns an array/tuple of three elements, and in order to extract the first of them - the pythonic way is to use

```
var1, var2, var3 = render_new_grant_email(gran)
```

But since you don't really need the last two, you can just take the first one (and use an unnamed variable for the last two):

```
var1, __, __ = render_new_grant_email(grant)
```

Or as in your original code:

```
response_html, __, __ = render_new_grant_email(grant)
```